# How to resize startup partition in Yosemite?

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I want to resize the startup partition but i have sort of problem, First I cant pull it down to resize it and if i change the value the options `(revert , apply)` wont show up, I tried to resize in the recovery but it gives this problem

```
couldn't unmount disk (error)
```

what should i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check if you have FileVault enabled, that will prohibit to changes in the partitions. After you disable it (System Preferences -> Security & Privacy, restart)

You can list the partitions using the command:

```
diskutil cs list
```

With this you can get the id of the volume,

And then resize with:

```
diskutil corestorage resizeVolume XXX-XXXXXXXX 10gb
```

Comment: with what i should replace the "x"s ?

Comment: When you do the cs list, you check the number of the partition you want to resize,

Comment: i did the cs list but it gives one found with different numbers which one

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qav587e4uwof1m5/Screen%20Shot%202015-08-29%20at%208.24.58%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: I typed diskutil corestorage resizeVolume Macintosh 20gb it worked thanks